# Java Method Override - "Method does not override method from super..."

Tags: java, inheritance

Coming from a C# background I have no idea what the issue is here.

I have my base class, which defines the abstract method, getContentValues

```
public abstract class BaseDataSource<T> {
    protected abstract ContentValues getContentValues(T object);
}
```

Inheriting from that is another class, IIdentifiableDataSource.

```
public abstract class IIdentifiableDataSource extends BaseDataSource<IIdentifiable>  {
    // Nothing in here is relevant to the getContentValues method.
}
```

Finally, inheriting from IIdentifiableDataSource, is the last child class MessagesDataSource, where getContentValues is overridden. It is throwing an error here that states "Method does not override method from its superclass"

```
public class MessagesDataSource extends IIdentifiableDataSource {
    @Override
    protected ContentValues getContentValues(Message object) {
        // fill ContentValues and return it.
    }
}
```

I imagine this has something to do the generic base class, but I'm unsure why.

Comment: look at the signature of the method... The parameter TYPE doesn't match. That's the problem. You are overloading not overriding (in your case would be implementing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MessagesDataSource` class is a `BaseDataSource<IIdentifiable>`, not a `BaseDataSource<Message>`.  The type of the parameter to `getContentValues` in `MessagesDataSource` must match the type parameter, `IIdentifiable`.

```
@Override
protected ContentValues getContentValues(IIdentifiable object) {
```

Or, if you must have `Message` instead as the parameter type, assuming that `Message` implements `IIdentifiableobject`, then the intermediate class `IIdentifiableDataSource` can define its own type parameter that `MessagesDataSource` can supply.

```
public abstract class IIdentifiableDataSource<T extends IIdentifiable>
    extends BaseDataSource<T>  {
```

Then `MessagesDataSource` can define `T` to be `Message`:

```
public class MessagesDataSource extends IIdentifiableDataSource<Message> {
```

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense now! I probably shouldn't be working on this little sleep anyways, haha.